# Split String With preg_match

Tags: php, arrays, split, preg-match, preg-match-all

I have string :

```
$productList="
Saluran Dua(Bothway)-(TAN007);
Speedy Password-(INET PASS);
Memo-(T-Memo);
7-pib r-10/10-(AM);
FBI (R/N/M)-(Rr/R(A));
";
```

i want the result like this:

```
Array(
[0]=>TAN007
[1]=>INET PASS
[2]=>T-Memo
[3]=>AM
[4]=>Rr/R(A)
);
```

I used :

```
$separator = '/\-\(([A-z ]*)\)/';
preg_match_all($separator, $productList, $match);
$value=$match[1];
```

but the result:

```
Array(
[0]=>INET PASS
[1]=>AM
);
```

there's must wrong code, anybody can help this?

Comment: Add numbers `0-9` and dash `-` to your regexp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

for the 1th line you need 0-9

for the 3th line you need a - in and

in the last line you need ()
try this

```
 #\-\(([a-zA-Z/0-9(\)\- ]*)\)#
```

Comment: `[A-z]` includes all the characters between `A` and `z`. As you can see from the [ASCII table](http://www.asciitable.com), it **contains** `A` to `Z`, `a` to `z` and 6 other characters: `[`, `\`, `]`, `^`, `_` and backquote [ **`** ] .

Comment: @axiac okay i didnt know, i removed that line.

Answer (score 3):

Your `regex` does not include all the characters that can appear in the piece of text you want to capture.

The correct `regex` is:

```
$match = array();
preg_match_all('/-\((.*)\);/', $productList, $match);
```

**Explanation** (from the inside to outside):

- `.*` matches anything;
- `(.*)` is the expression above put into parenthesis to capture the match in `$match[1]`;
- `-\((.*)\);` is the above in the context: it matches if it is preceded by `-(` and followed by `);`; the parenthesis are escaped to use their literal values and not their special `regex` interpretation;
- there is no need to escape `-` in regex; it has special interpretation only when it is used inside character ranges (`[A-Z]`, f.e.) but even there, if the dash character (`-`) is right after the `[` or right before the `]` then it has no special meaning; e.g. `[-A-Z]` means: dash (`-`) or any capital letter (`A` to `Z`).

Now, `print_r($match[1]);` looks like this:

```
Array
(
    [0] => TAN007
    [1] => INET PASS
    [2] => T-Memo
    [3] => AM
    [4] => Rr/R(A)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

try with this ReGex

```
$separator = '#\-\(([A-Za-z0-9/\-\(\) ]*)\)#';
```